# Swapping text in an HTML file

Tags: html, powershell

I want to update a bit of text in an HTML file.  The text in the HTML file:

```html
<html><body>Normal</body></html>
```

I want to change `Normal` to `Rollout` and vice versa.  My code at first was

```psh
(Get-Content C:\temp\a.html) |
ForEach-Object {$_ -replace "Normal", "Rollout"} |
Set-Content C:\temp\a.html
```

This worked great, except I want to run the same script to change it back from rollout to normal.  I was trying some if else if's but that didn't work either.  Below is one of many attempts using the `if..elseif`:

```psh
$a = Get-Content C:\temp\a.html
(Get-Content c:\temp\a.html) |
if($a -match "Normal")
{
ForEach-Object {$_ -replace "Normal", "Rollout"} 
} |
Elseif($a -match "Rollout")
{
ForEach-Object {$_ -replace "Rollout", "Normal"}
} |
Set-Content C:\temp\b.html
```

How can I approach this differently?

Answer (score 3):

Using `[regex]::replace`, with a script block delegate and a substitution hash:

```
$replace = @{
Normal = 'Rollout'
Rollout = 'Normal'
}

$x = @(
'<html><body>Normal</body></html>'
'<html><body>Rollout</body></html>'
)

$x | foreach { [regex]::Replace( $_,'(Normal|Rollout)',{$replace[$args[0].value]} ) }

<html><body>Rollout</body></html>
<html><body>Normal</body></html>
```

That will toggle it between "Normal" and "Rollout"

Answer (score 2):

I'd use the `[xml]` type to edit the node directly rather than doing a string replace.

```
$html = [xml](Get-Content c:\temp\a.html)
$html.html.body = "Rollout"
$html.InnerXml | Set-Content C:\temp\b.html
```

Comment: Probably not a very advisable approach. Attempting to cast html to xml can go wrong in so many ways... You only need to add an empty element like `<br>` to the mix and you will end up with an "InvalidCastToXmlDocument" exception.

Answer (score 2):

If/ElseIf can go horribly wrong, and the #1 error I've seen in cases like this are lines that contain neither Normal or Rollout, and don't get passed through. Obviously there are several answers to this problem, and to be honest I'd go with mjolinor's answer because it's probably the fastest because, well, RegEx is awesome. But, since it looks like you don't want to go that route I would suggest replacing your If/ElseIf statement with the Switch statement, because it's just better.

```
$(Switch -RegEx (Get-Content C:\Path\To\File.html){
    "Normal" {$_ -replace "Normal", "Rollout"; Continue}
    "Rollout" {$_ -replace "Rollout", "Normal"; Continue}
    default {$_}
}) | Set-Content C:\Path\To\File.html
```

This actually runs very similarly to what you have already. Instead of saying If this/ElseIf/That the `Switch` cmdlet takes each line, and in this case because I used the `-RegEx` argument it tries to match each line against the first case (matches for "Normal"). If it finds a match it performs the following scriptblock (passes that line through, replacing "Normal" with "Rollout", and then runs the `Continue` command, which will cause the loop to move to the next item).

It then moves to the second case, where it tries to match the line against "Rollout" and if it finds it it performs the scriptblock for that case, where it passes through the line replacing "Rollout" with "Normal", and again runs `Continue` to move to the next item.

Then it moves to the default case which runs for anything, and passes through the line as is.

It runs that whole `Switch` loop within a sub-expression, and all of the output is piped to the `Set-Content` cmdlet to write the file.

Now, like I said, I would go with mjolinor's answer for speed and simplicity, but this I think is a better way to run your solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You were close. Here's a solution adapted from your original code:

```
(Get-Content C:\temp\a.html) |
ForEach-Object {
    if($_ -match "Normal") { $_ -replace "Normal", "Rollout"} 
    elseif($_ -match "Rollout") { $_ -replace "Rollout", "Normal"}
} | 
Set-Content C:\temp\a.html
```

Comment: Ah, i think I like your approach better.  A little more simple that what I ended up with.

Comment: Well, I did try this code to simplify it, however it didn't change the text for me.  No error, just no change.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I thought of a different approach on my own and figured this code out which worked perfectly for me!

```psh
$a = Get-Content C:\temp\b.html
if ($a -match "Normal") {
  (Get-Content c:\temp\b.html) |
    ForEach-Object {$_ -replace "Normal", "Rollout"} |
    Set-Content C:\temp\b.html
} elseif($a -match "Rollout") {
  (Get-Content c:\temp\b.html) |
    ForEach-Object {$_ -replace "Rollout", "Normal"} |
    Set-Content C:\temp\b.html
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A different approach using the Internet Explorer COM object:

```psh
$file = 'C:\path\to\your.html'

$ie = New-Object -COM 'InternetExplorer.Application'
$ie.Navigate("file://$file")

do { Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100 } until ($ie.ReadyState -eq 4)

$ie.Document.body.innerText = switch ($ie.Document.body.innerText) {
  'Normal'  { 'Rollout' }
  'Rollout' { 'Normal' }
}

$ie.Document.documentElement.outerHtml | Set-Content $file

$ie.Quit()
```